# Zechuto Yagen/Tagen Alenu?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

Why is it that many people say זכותו יגן עלינו - according to grammar, shouldn't it be תגן עלינו since זכות is feminine?

I guess I am just looking for a justification of the general practice.

Comment: Google has twice as many results for [זכותו תגן עלינו](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&source=hp&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=2#hl=en&gbv=2&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95+%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9F+%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95&oq=%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95&gs_l=hp.3.0.35i39j0i19l9.831.3136.1.4584.6.6.0.0.0.0.102.449.5j1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.8.hp.Br_5stFX8Sw&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.dmg&fp=d14b4293a52428ed&biw=1304&bih=707) as for [זכותו יגן עלינו](http://bit.ly/ZI7tXM)

Comment: I'm just asking why I see זי״ע in many sefarim and not זת״ע. And saying they were ignorant to such a basic rule in grammar isn't a good answer I'm my opinion

Comment: @DoubleAA https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95+%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9F+%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%22 (5120 first-page estimate) vs. https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95+%D7%99%D7%92%D7%9F+%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%22 (85200 first-page estimate).

Answer (score 2):

In Medieval Rabbinic literature nouns with suffixes were generally seen as grammatically male, hence the זכותו יגן instead of זכותו תגן.

See http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA#cite_note-6